# RSA Archer - how to show video or execute .exe file in an iView

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I would like to show a video or run an .exe file that shows a video, inside an iView. I noticed that I have the following possibilities to manage a file:
http: //
file://
ftp: //
mailto:
news:
related:

in the primary graphic section. More pexactly, within the iView I would like to have 3 icons on the left with a link next to it that allows me to view a different videos, opening an additional window, as I could do by executing a url for a cloud video.
I assume I should use file: // but if I have to set the path of the file on the server where Archer is installed, will the path be absolute or relative? I don't know if Archer can be installed only on Windows or even on Linux.

I would also like to add an icon, not present among those I could select. In this case, what size should the icon have, for example with a .png extension?

Thank you in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

You’re best bet Giovanni is to use a custom iView instead and follow normal HTML conventions to display what you want.

FYI, exe execution is browser controlled, not Archer.

Feel free and head to the RSA community (https://community.rsa.com) and search for supporting documentation and robust community of users of Archer.

Comment: Hi DjP and thank you for your suggestion. I tried to see where to post the same question in RSA Archer Link for Archer GRC. I see the possibility to ask a question or start a discussion for the following products:

Comment: Just follow the instructions here to get access, https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-84947